# Steiner Formula and Quermassintegral of an Interval and a Unit Ball

Tags: volume

Related to **Steiner Formula** (which gives a polynomial expansion of Volume after Minkowski Sum of a Convex Body and Ball with some radius $r$):

I want to know what would be $quermassintegral$ of an Interval and a Unit Ball (all $quermassintegral$'s, i.e.: from first to n-th.)

Note: I am not sure if $quermassintegral$ is the correct name, but what I mean are terms in the expansion, other than powers of the radius and binomial coefficients.

I have already checked couple books now, but neither are explicitly providing a way to find out an answer for my question. Text/Book advice would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You answered your own question with *the same* book reference *twice*. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665385/mean-width-and-diamk/2749238#2749238 . Please stop this nonsense.

Comment: This is not a nonsense, please check the book. The book explains both the relation between the mean-width and diameter of a Convex Hull, and give precise statement and explanation for Steiner's Formula. Quermassintegrals and Mixed Volumes are defined as well in the meantime.

Comment: The book is nice, indeed, buy you answering your own questions *twice* with the same book recommendation *is nonsense*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hug, Daniel; Weil, Wolfgang, $\textit{A Course on Convex Geometry}$. Very nice book if you are interested in Convex Geometry; explains the above mentioned property.